# BeautifulSoup4 print and modify selected row from set of array

Tags: python, arrays, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm extracting data from [UWC](https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/5292/uwc-berhad).
My intention is to print out some selected row, and if needed, I can freely modify the output given. Here is my code :

```
def companyKLScreenerDetail('https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/5292'):

    klseLink = requests.get(str(klselink), headers=header)
    klseParser = BeautifulSoup(klseLink.text, 'html.parser')
    
    currentQuarterReportTables = klseParser.find('table', {'class': 'financial_reports table table-hover table-sm table-theme'}).findAll('tr')
    for row in currentQuarterReportTables:
        cells = row.findAll('td')
        output = []
        for i, cell in enumerate(cells):
            output.append(cell.text.strip())
        print(output)
```

This is my output for the moment (notethat it's also print out empty []):

```
[]
['3.95', '0.000', '0.4300', '71,500k', '21,708k', '1', '2020-10-31', '31 Jul, 2021', '2020-12-01', '93.6%', 'View']
['3.39', '2.000', '0.4100', '61,406k', '18,648k', '4', '2020-07-31', '31 Jul, 2020', '2020-09-03', '85.1%', 'View']
['2.65', '0.000', '0.3700', '55,796k', '14,593k', '3', '2020-04-30', '31 Jul, 2020', '2020-06-04', '65.4%', 'View']
['3.63', '0.000', '0.5200', '54,938k', '13,310k', '2', '2020-01-31', '31 Jul, 2020', '2020-03-05', '0%', 'View']
['3.06', '0.000', '0.5100', '46,910k', '11,215k', '1', '2019-10-31', '31 Jul, 2020', '2019-11-15', '0%', 'View']
['2.75', '0.000', '0.4800', '46,908k', '10,074k', '4', '2019-07-31', '31 Jul, 2019', '2019-09-03', '0%', 'View']
['2.97', '0.000', '0.3700', '38,308k', '8,822k', '3', '2019-04-30', '31 Jul, 2019', '2019-07-01', '0%', 'View']
```

Earlier, I tried by using `print(output[1])` but it always give me `'IndexError: list index out of range'`, thus I think I can't freely pick and adjust the data inside. For example, from :

```
['3.95', '0.000', '0.4300', '71,500k', '21,708k', '1', '2020-10-31', '31 Jul, 2021', '2020-12-01', '93.6%', 'View']
```

I will pick `0.4300` to be multiply with `1.232` later, and save the multiplication result into new variable.
I also plan to print those selected row into :

```
['0.000', '0.4300', '71,500k', '21,708k', '1', '2020-10-31', '31 Jul, 2021', '2020-12-01', '93.6%']
```

later.

Really stuck here for the moment. Thanks for your helps! Really appreciate!

Comment: If I am not wrong, do you want all data in one row?

Comment: No, I just want to print selected row/data. As you can see, the 'View' is not a data but a button named 'View'. And I only need 4 top row data only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `[]` list because there is a one (first one) that have no td. So your output was 7 rows of list.

You can try this:

```
  output = []
    for row in currentQuarterReportTables[1:]:
        res = [td.text.strip() for td in row.findAll("td")]
        output.append(res)
    print(output)
    print(len(output))
```

Comment: I can access row by row by adjusting print(output[1]) as example. How can I put this result in variable? So I can perform any equation on it

Comment: You could use pandas to do import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns=["col" +str(i) for i in range(1,12)])
print(df)

Comment: Hi Samsul, how can I print only the top 4 row, with only the first 5 column?

Comment: Also, I try your code:
output = []
for row in currentQuarterReportTables[1:]:
    res = [td.text.strip() for td in row.findAll("td")]
    res = res[0]
    output.append(res)
    #I want to have the result 3.39 here to store into variable
print(output[1])
How can I achieve this?

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns=['col'+str(i) for i in range(1,12)])
print(df.loc[:3,['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4','col5']])

print(df.loc[1,['col1']])
res =df.loc[1][0]
res2 =df.loc[3][0]
print()
print(res)
print(res2)

Comment: Thanks, you're really helps my progress a lot!